# Regex to match 1 but not 10,11,12, etc or 21, 31, etc

Tags: regex

I'm trying to find the proper regex to match:

`?page=1`

but I don't want to match `?page=10` or `?page=11` or `?page=12` ..etc to `?page=19`

and I don't want to match `?page=21` or `?page=31` ...etc

I just want to be able to match `?page=1`

I've tried `?page=1[^0123456789]`  but it doesn't seem to be working for me.

Comment: Knowing which language could help...

Comment: Knowing what the string you're looking in can look like would also help. Is this part the end of the string or can there be more?

Comment: Yes, sorry, your end of string answer below works for me.  Sorry about the poor details.  First time posting here.  I'll add more next time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would page=2 be ok? If not, I don't understand why you're doing this with regex. Using a substr/strpos/strcmp-equivalent function would be more appropriate.

In these examples, I'm assuming that `?page=1` is the end of the string.

If page=(a number from 0 to 9) would be ok, you need to use `\?page=\d$` (`\d means "a digit"`)

If page should only be 1, then it's `\?page=1$`

`$ = End of string`

The problem is that the `?` has a special meaning in regular expressions, and needs to be escaped.

Comment: +1 for pointing out that `== "?page=1"` seems to be all that's needed. There's nothing complicated enough to require a regular expression

Comment: @Gareth. That depends on the context of the issue. maybe it can be any number, not just 1 etc'.

Comment: @Gareth how about "domain.com?page=1". My understanding is that he want to match ?page=1 within a longer string

Comment: If this would be PHP, I would prefer `substr($str, -7) == "?page=1"`

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape `?`:

```
\?page=1
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/SgsYd/) in javascript.

If you want to match only strings that this is their value:

```
^\?page=1$ // '^'- starts with ...  '$' - ends with...
```

If you want any one digit not just `1`:

```
^\?page=\d$
\?page=\d // Or this
```

Comment: I was going to say +1 for the demo but I think the demo could be improved. As he said, he did NOT want to match page=14 etc.